# IIS Rewrite Multiple URLS to Ports

Tags: iis, iis-7, rewrite, iis-7.5, iis-6

I have two processes/apps running on port 8888 & port 8890.

I can access them in my windows server with http://localhost:8888 & http://localhost:8890.

I am currently using IIS GUI for rewriting URLs. Application Request Routing(ARR) & URL Rewrite are installed.

I have been successful in rewriting or redirecting all requests which hit the server to one port - essentially I map '*' wildcard to 'http://localhost:8888/{R:0}' and it works when I access http://website!

How can I extend this to the following scenario:

http://website/solution1/ should redirect to port 8888 & 
http://website/solution2/ should redirect to port 8890

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (in your web.config) should work:

```
<rule name="solution1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(solution1/)(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8888/{R:2}" />
</rule>
<rule name="solution2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(solution2/)(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8890/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

IIRC, the `{R:0}` will match the entire URL, so you don't want that in this case. Instead, with the `(` and `)` you define 'capturing groups'; `{R:2}` will be *everything* after `solution1/` or `solution2/`.

<sub>If you're set on using the IIS GUI, I hope you'll be able to find the fields that need to be filled; they are the same ones you already use, only with different parameters.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, This is not working. When I access http://website/solution1/url1/, its throwing a 404 error.

The URL in the browser becomes http://website/url1/. So I guess the rewrite happens but it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Do you get the same 404 when visiting http://localhost:8888/url1 ?

Comment: Yes. I do get a 404.

Comment: Can you check with a localhost:8888 URL which *does* work?

Comment: Is there any setting I have to enable in ARR? I have checked the "Enable Proxy" checkbox. But I haven't checked the "Use URL Rewrite to check incoming requests". Do I have to enable it?

Comment: I often forget to switch on the "Enable Proxy". In my setup, it works without "Use URL Rewrite to check incoming requests".

Comment: URLs in the browser are not supposed to change when rewrite is configured. I’m guessing your rule may have a redirect instead lf rewrite as the action type?